# Processing drone Images of body of water?

Tags: image, digital-image-processing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pix4d, opendronemap

I took some pictures of a body of a body of water using a multi-spectral sensor attached to drone. When trying to process the image using Pix4D, more than 50% of pictures were unable to calibrated.

I contacted their customer support to see is there was something that I was doing wrong and their answer was that "images that capture only water, cannot be calibrated (optimize internal and external orientation of the camera). The reason is that it is very hard to find key-points on water surfaces (water is very uniform)".

I am wondering if there is something that I can try in order to stitch all of my images.

Comment: This answer to another question may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280675/115

Comment: Thank you @PolyGeo for the link; it was really helpful to understand more about the problem that I am having. However, I am still trying to look for a possible alternative to overcome the issue (if any off course) .

Comment: I've seen Agisoft Photoscan have better luck stitching spectral images where pix4d and others wouldn't, but it isn't a guarantee.